# Regex - Find Tag with linebreak

Tags: html, regex

How to find the `<span>LINEBREAK</span>` Tags in the middle ( the second opening and closing `span` Tags ) ?

```
<span>
Some Text
</span>
<span>

</span>
<span>
Some other Text
</span>
```

If is use `<span>` I can find the opening Tag. If I use `<\/span>` I can find the closing Tag. If i use `^\s*$` I can find the Linebreak. But how can I combine all three ?

`<span>^\s*$<\/span>` doesn't work.

I also tried `<span>\n^\s*$\n<\/span>` and `<span>\r\n^\s*$\r\n<\/span>`.

Comment: Which language are you writing the regex in? Javascript?

Comment: Make sure you have the multi line flag enabled: https://regex101.com/r/ecbsj0/1

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below. This will match any span with a linebreak in it.

```
<span>(\r\n|\r|\n)</span>
```

If above code isn't working try this. This will find any span with *zero to unlimited* newlines.

```
<span>(\n)*</span>
```

Comment: Thanks **Red**. This does not work. I tried to add the Whitespaces but also not working: ``<span>(\r\n|\r|\n).*<\/span>``
But this works: ``<span>(\r\n|\r|\n|\n\n).*<\/span>``

Comment: Testing this in https://regex101.com/ it works fine. Without more information I can't realy an better answer.

Comment: I agree and apologise for the missing Information. Thank you!

Comment: What finally with the Python Code worked is this: ``<span>\s*\n\s*<\/span>`` I guess because of some leading Whitespaces. But you helped me a lot to find the right Answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this
`<span>.*?\r\n^$\r\n.*?</span>`

This will search for new empty lines inside `<span>` tags